# formula for getting the least amount in the last column

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for a formula, that given $x ≥ 5$ , it will split $x$ over 3 columns with the least amount in the 3rd column, however the 3rd column must be > 0.

so where $x = 5$ it would look like:

2|2|1

or $x = 16$

6|6|4

Comment: Split $x$ as follows: $x|0|0$.

Comment: i'm not really sure what that means.  in english what would that be?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for. What do you mean by "splitting" a number $x$? It looks like you're choosing three values that add up to $x$, and my suggestion is in particular to choose $0$ for the last column. How did you come up with $2|2|1$ given 5? Why not $5|0|0$, or $3|2|0$, etc.?

Comment: Are you looking to split them such that the numbers are integers as close to $x/3$ as possible?

Comment: i'm sorry i haven't made this clear enough.  I'm trying to make it so that columns 1 and 2 have an exen distribution as possible and column 3 has the least amount, unless it can be split equally over all 3 columns

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, Michael's answer below answers the question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=3k$, split them $k|k|k$.

If $n=3k+1$, split them $k+1|k+1|k-1$.

If $n=3k+2$, split them $k+1|k+1|k$.

Comment: are you saying that if n mod 3 = 1 then  split them k+1, k+1, k-1.  Wouldn't that make 7 mod 3 = 1, so you'd end up with 4 4? 0?

Comment: If $7=3k+1$ then $k=2$, so split them $3|3|1$

Comment: Maths was never my strong point.  SO to be honest I'm really not sure where $k$ is coming from or what it even means.  Are you saying it's $7/3 = 2$.  Is there a a way of making it so a 5 year old can understand? scratch that a 2 year old.

Comment: Deal one per column until you are nearly finished.  The first two columns need an equal amount so you need an even number of cards at the end.  That is, 0 2 or 4 cards.  So with 7 cards, each column gets 1.  $1|1|1$  You have 4 cards left over, so the first two columns get 2 more each.  So now, $3|3|1$